# Nesting two preg_replace in php

Tags: php

How can I nest these two preg_replace in PHP

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/','',$str); // This one goes first
$str = preg_replace('#[ -\s]+#','-',$str); // Then this one
```

By nesting I mean do it in a single line:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/','',$str)+the other one.
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$str = preg_replace('#[ -\s]+#','-', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/','',$str));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, although I'm not sure why you want to do it. It's much more readable to have them on separate lines. Here you go anyway:

```
$str = preg_replace('#[ -\s]+#', '-', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', '', $str));
```